# Permission of ~/.Trash is always gone after Time machine backup

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, permission, trash

[image: corrupted Trash]

Every day, permission of `~/.Trash` is always gone(Pic1). And `.Trash` become zero bytes file.

That mean, I can't move files to Trash, and Finder will delete files immediately.

Every time `~/.Trash` go wrong, I fix the problem by `sudo rm -ri ~/.Trash` and reboot mac, to create new Trash with normal permission. But, trash won't work again just after 1~2 hour.

- (Permission of Trash on iCloud Drive is not affected-which means I can still remove files on iCloud Drive to trash.)

**What I tried**

- `sudo rm -ri ~/.Trash`
- remove and recreate `.Trash` on the iCloud path too.
- use 'Appy enclosed items...' from home folder.
- just don't use any kinds of 'optimization app' or 'cleaner app.'
- reinstall clean macOS.
- use disktuil on an internal drive and external drives.

**Maybe...**

I guess the problem comes with Time Machine backup, but I don't know why.

Because I found that, whenever Time Machine auto-backup starts and done, next time I boot the mac, it happens again.

It happens for both wired external Time machine drive and wireless drive on Nas, and it happens even I clean up the external drive and restart Time machine from the empty drive.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by checking which process use `.Trash` path by `lsof | grep ~/.Trash`

I found that the background service of VyprVPN app use /.Trash (still I don't know why). So I clean up VyprVPN app. Problem solved.